# jquery autocomplete in SlickGrid issues

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, slickgrid

col1I've been trying to add the jquery autocomplete editor into my SlickGrid (2.0) per several suggestions but I keep getting an error:

> **Object doesn't support this property or method**

Here's what I'm trying to start with:

```
(function($) {

  // register namespace
  $.extend(true, window, {
    "Slick": {
      "Editors": {
        "Auto": AutoCompleteEditor,
        "SelectDD": SelectBoxEditor,
        "Select": SelectBoxEditor2,
        "Text": TextEditor,
        "Text2": IntegerCellEditor
      }
    }
  });

  var availableTags = [
                        "ActionScript",
                        "AppleScript",
                        "Asp",
                        "BASIC",
                        "C",
                        "C++",
                        "Clojure",
                        "COBOL",
                        "ColdFusion",
                        "Erlang",
                        "Fortran",
                        "Groovy",
                        "Haskell",
                        "Java",
                        "JavaScript",
                        "Lisp",
                        "Perl",
                        "PHP",
                        "Python",
                        "Ruby",
                        "Scala",
                        "Scheme"
                      ];

   function AutoCompleteEditor(args) {
     var $input;
     var defaultValue;
     var scope = this;
     var calendarOpen = false;

     this.init = function () {
       $input = $("<INPUT id='tags' class='editor-text' />");
       $input.appendTo(args.container);
       $input.focus().select();
       $input.autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
     };

     this.destroy = function () {
       $input.autocomplete("destroy");
     };

     this.focus = function () {
       $input.focus();
     };

     this.loadValue = function (item) {
       defaultValue = item[args.column.field];
       $input.val(defaultValue);
       $input[0].defaultValue = defaultValue;
       $input.select();
     };

     this.serializeValue = function () {
       return $input.val();
     };

     this.applyValue = function (item, state) {
       item[args.column.field] = state;
     };

     this.isValueChanged = function () {
       return (!($input.val() == "" && defaultValue == null)) && ($input.val() != defaultValue);
     };

     this.validate = function () {
       return {
         valid: true,
         msg: null
       };
     };

     this.init();
   }
```

and here is the relevant portion of the Grid:

```
var columns = [
{id:"col1", name:"test", field:"col1",  width:135, editable:true, cssClass:"pad-4-left", sortable:true, editor:Slick.Editors.Auto},
```

I've included what was said to be the dependancies:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE -
It turns out that I was getting interference apparently from this jquery module: jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js.
I did a workaround and also needed to use an earlier version of jquery.min (jquery-1.7.2.min.js) since the later 1.8.3 version was also throwing errors in my existing application.
Both "fixes" were implemented and now I'm up & running.